# Is there some special case where a fermion can mediate a force?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, interactions, carrier-particles

Looking at the comments of this questions
[Does the gravitino contribute to the gravitational interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134549/) and even considering that the answers here in this other question [Why are all force particles bosons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81414/) do explain why a force carrier needs to be bosonic, I still wonder if there are some particular cases where a fermion similar to a gaugino could mediate a force.

A case in mind, that could avoid the issues on angular momentum conservation, is zero-range interactions ("contact" interactions). Still, I can not see how such beast could be described with a Lorentz invariant Lagrangian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be tricky, since any force mediator (at least from conventional thinking) must have a three-valent vertex, two of which are the charged object and one of them is the force carrier. If the force carrier is a fermion, I don't think this combination can be Lorentz invariant (spin zero combination).

Comment: Yep, it seems that a Lorentz invariant single term in the lagrangian is not possible. And still I am a bit uneasy about a definite no.

Comment: @arivero, I understand and for the same reason, my answer is measured.

Answer (score 7):

It depends  on your definition of force. Force means a change in momentum, ~dp/dt  , so any change in momentum in a Feynman diagram is a force. For example this diagram for compton scattering

[image: compton scattering]

says yes.

If one is talking of gauge theories and exchanged bosons , because those are the ones that build up the  three, electromagnetic, weak, strong ( maybe four if gravity is unified) forces , then no, by the construction.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you would accept as a valid answer but two bosons could feel a small force resulting from a virtual fermion loop for example. Does that count?

Comment: I wonder if the fermion loop is equivalent to a composite bosonic operator $\langle \bar{\psi} \psi \rangle$ mediating the force.

Comment: Hmm that looks as an exchange of a meson, does it?

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to put a vev $\langle \rangle$ above. @arivero: Yes, that's what I was wondering -- the composite force mediating degree-of-freedom is again bosonic, now!

Comment: I would expect that some regularisation technique for the four-leg fermi interaction could be using this kind of fermion loops. But by becoming a boson, they already allow to substitute the zero-range by a finite range. A regularisation keeping the property of "zero range" would be a lot more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the need of having a Lorentz invariant term, there is another "against" that comes only when we consider classic fields. If we restore units, a Planck constant appears in the kinetic term of the fermion field, telling that it will disappear in the limit $\hbar \to 0$. But of course this "non-go" argument is bypassed by any macroscopic electrical current.

Comment: Could you please share the computations? Thanks in advance